# Save from device as CMYK high resolution tiff file

Tags: r, resolution, tiff

I need to save my par plots in R as a high resolution tiff file and using the CMYK colormodel for a publication to a particular journal.  I've attempted something like the following:

```
tiff("test.tiff", colormodel = 'cmyk')
```

code....

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot()
```

more code..

```
par(new=TRUE)
plot()
```

Unfortunately, it does not work.

I've also tried EPS but the publishing website has this online artwork quality tester and failed the EPS files for being too low on resolution.

Here is a working example similar in concept to what I need.

```
tiff(file = "test.tiff", res = 1200, colormodel = 'cmyk') 
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
plot(1,3)             
par(new=TRUE) 
plot(3,5) 
plot(2,3) 
par(new=TRUE) 
plot(4,2) 
dev.print(tiff, file = "test.tiff", width = 1680, height = 1050)
```

This still doens't work. The publishing website says it is still in RGB format and the resolution is only 72 dpi. Any thoughts?

Comment: What does not work exactly? I think a fully reproducible example would help a lot here.

Comment: Please edit the code into your question above, and not as a comment.

Comment: In addition to `res`, have you tried explicitly specifying the `width`, `height`, and `units` arguments to `tiff()`, and then doing your plotting and calling `dev.off()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a png file (in the RGB space) in R

```
png("/tmp/a.png", width=6, height=6, units="cm", res=1200)
plot(1)
dev.off()
```

and convert it to TIFF outside R.
For instance, with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php):

```
convert -colorspace CMYK a.png a.tiff
identify -verbose a.tiff   # To check the result
# Image: a.tiff
#   Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
#   Class: DirectClass
#   Geometry: 2834x2834+0+0
#   Resolution: 472.44x472.44
#   Print size: 5.99865x5.99865
#   Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
#   Type: ColorSeparation
#   Base type: ColorSeparation
#   Endianess: MSB
#   Colorspace: CMYK
#   ...
```

Comment: Generating tiff by R and then converting into tiff with -colorspace CMYK also work.